# How to Write Attributed text in Two UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nsrange

In my application I want to write **15 Font Size** Attributed Text (like Bold, Italic, Underline) in **One UITextView**.

And Want to get that **same text** written **in 35 Font Size** Attributed Text in **Another UITextView**.

I did All the Attribute text Write task in UITextView.

But don't get how to write same text in another UITextView in same Time with Different Font Size.
I need to define *different* **NSMutableParagraphStyle** For both the UITextView.

My Code For just Bold Text is

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
 UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName :font};
    [txtView1 setTypingAttributes:attributes];

 UIFont *font35 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:35];
    NSDictionary *attributes35 = @{NSFontAttributeName :font35};
    [txtView2 setTypingAttributes:attributes35];

NSMutableAttributedString *mat = [txtViewOfNotes.attributedText mutableCopy];
            [mat addAttributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)} range:NSMakeRange (range.location-1, 1)];
txtView1.attributedText = mat;

NSMutableAttributedString *mat = [txtViewOfNotes.attributedText mutableCopy];
            [mat addAttributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)} range:NSMakeRange (range.location-1, 1)];
txtView2.attributedText = mat;


}
```

Any kind of Idea, code, or tutorial will be great Help.

Comment: Show some code you tried

Comment: You can try one thing , use NSAttributedString to apply you custome font scheme.

Comment: Can you guys please see my above Code...

Comment: So. what is problem you are seeing ...text not getting changed for both or fot only one ?

Comment: How you are setting the attributed text ?

Comment: @SamkitJain i need to write text in one UITextView and want to get that text in Another UITextView. but when i am typing the text i got in only one UITextView and not in Both. and if i am doing textview1.attributedText = textview2.attributedText. then Font size will not change.

Comment: Try my answer ...that should work @Sam

Comment: @SamkitJain Can you please look at my new edit in code. whatever you are saying is okay but it is not working with "setTypingAttributes" and Underline attribute property

Comment: if you have any idea to get text in one UITextView and the same text in another UITextView then please tell me. rest i'll manage.

Comment: In the same delegate method, you have to just get the text from replacementText:(NSString *)text
and set the text for both textViews...try my answer I am doing same there

Comment: Is this working now...?

Comment: No. and after i try to use observer to call the "shouldChangeTextInRange" method. but this is also giving me the "NSInvalidArgumentException" error.

Comment: If you have gmail id, lets have a chat on mrsamkitjain@gmail.com..i ll help u

Comment: I sent you an invitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the attributes and then change the text for both textViews.
So, use as the following :

```
NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:text];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
[title addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];
titleView1.attributedText = title;

 UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:35];
[title addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];
titleView1.attributedText = title;
```